# How to retrieve attribute from ControllerAdvice selector in ControllerAdvice class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I can define a Spring ControllerAdvice that is selectively used by a subset of controllers using a custom annotation:

```
@RestController
@UseAdviceA
@RequestMapping("/myapi")
class ApiController {
 ...
}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = UseAdviceA.class)
class AdviceA {

 ...
}
```

But is it possible to pass in an attribute via the custom annotation where the advice class can pick up from the annotation? For e.g.:

```
@RestController
@UseAdviceA("my.value")
@RequestMapping("/myapi")
class ApiController {
 ...
}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = UseAdviceA.class)
class AdviceA {
 // Some way to get the string "myvalue" from the instance of UseAdviceA
 ...
}
```

Any other way to achieve the same outcome, which is to be able to define a custom configuration at the Controller method which can be passed to the ControllerAdvice would be much appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.
Given

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UseAdviceA {
  public String myValue();
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@UseAdviceA(myValue = "ApiController")
@RequestMapping("/myapi")
class ApiController {
 ...
}
```

Your Controller Advice should be like

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = {UseAdviceA.class})
class AdviceA {

  @ExceptionHandler({SomeException.class})
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleSomeException(SomeException pe, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
    String value = handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(UseAdviceA.class).myValue();
     //value will be ApiController
    return new ResponseEntity<>("SomeString", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
```