# How to find controller name in @controllerAdvice or @RestControllerAdvice in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-aop

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

        @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<Error> handle(NoHandlerFoundException ex){
            String message = "HTTP " + ex.getHttpMethod() + " for " + ex.getRequestURL() + " is not supported.";
            Error error = new Error(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), message);
            return new ResponseEntity<Error>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
```

1. I am using @ControllerAdvice with @ExceptionHandler.
2. I need to get the exception occurred controller class name and package name or class object inside the handle method

Comment: checkout my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882476/how-to-retrieve-attribute-from-controlleradvice-selector-in-controlleradvice-cla/47885256#47885256

Comment: @pvpkiran thanks for the suggestion but without custom annotation i need a alternate answer so that i dont want to refactor all the controllers . i can able to change the advised controller not any other else

Comment: I have added the answer below. It is pretty much same. only difference is argument in `@ControlelrAdvice` is removed. Now it matches any controllers instead of controllers with custom annotations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work

```
@ControllerAdvice
class AdviceA {

  @ExceptionHandler({SomeException.class})
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleSomeException(SomeException pe, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
    Class controllerClass = handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass();
    //controllerClass.toString will give you fully qualified name
    return new ResponseEntity<>("SomeString", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
```

Comment: Intentionally calling `GET` resource with `PUT` method to validate `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` and defined the controoler  `@ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<String>> handle(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException exception,
            ServletWebRequest req, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {}` and facing the error : Could not resolve method parameter at index 2 - No suitable resolver for argument 2 of type 'org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod`

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This gives class info. Can we get method name ?

Comment: I think you can. `handlerMethod.getMethod().toString()`

Comment: Can you show the code for the controller calling the exception with MethodHandler ?