# How to print the Controller method name in @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: spring-boot, controller-advice

I went through link: [How to find controller name in @controllerAdvice or @RestControllerAdvice in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922306/how-to-find-controller-name-in-controlleradvice-or-restcontrolleradvice-in-spr) many times, but I am looking to get the Controller methodname in @ControllerAdvice class.

Here is my CustomHandler Class.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    ........
    ..........
    ..........

    @ExceptionHandler({DataExistsException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleDataExistsException(RuntimeException e, WebRequest request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse response, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        // Here I am looking to print Controller endpoint method name

        LoggingUtil.printJsonReq(httpRequest, HttpStatus.valueOf("BAD_REQUEST").value(), LoggingUtil.getTime(httpRequest), null, response);
        return handleExceptionInternal(e, getErrors(error), getHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`HandlerMethod`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html) should give you this information. Quoting the documentation:

> Encapsulates information about a handler method consisting of a [method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html#getMethod--) and a [bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html#getBean--). Provides convenient access to method parameters, the method return value, method annotations, etc.

So you can use:

```java
Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find out the method name from the RuntimeException so that would be

```
 e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```